# When Control.ParentChanged Event occurs?

Tags: c#, winforms

I read about Control.ParentChanged Event on MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged(VS.71).aspx

But I don't understand the sample code: there's no ParentChanged at all appearing in source code ?

```
private void currencyTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      // Convert the text to a Double and determine if it is a negative number.
      if(double.Parse(currencyTextBox.Text) < 0)
      {
         // If the number is negative, display it in Red.
         currencyTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Red;
      }
      else
      {
         // If the number is not negative, display it in Black.
         currencyTextBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      // If there is an error, display the text using the system colors.
      currencyTextBox.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
   }
}
```

So I don't understand what Control.ParentChanged Event is or does.

Answer (score 4):

Hehe, they just couldn't come up with a good example.  And punted by showing a generic FooChanged event handler instead.  Yeah, useless.

It is quite unusual to implement a ParentChanged event handler yourself.  It's a big deal in the Winforms internals, properties like BackColor, ForeColor, Font are 'ambient' properties.  If they are not overridden from the default then they'll get the value of the Parent.  Which of course means that it is *really* important to notice that the parent changed.  The winforms code already takes care of it, you very rarely have to worry about it.  Unless you create your own ambient property of course.

Answer (score 0):

There would be another piece of code elsewhere that registers this as an event handler:

```
currencyTextBox.ParentChanged += new EventHandler(currencyTextBox_TextChanged);
```

However, I agree - the method name is misleading.

This event handler will fire when you change the parent control of this control to a different parent control.

You may want to read up on [raising and consuming events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9aackb16.aspx).